# About the generalized Shanks' identity.

Tags: calculus

There is interesting equality by [this](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-1/letter1.pdf) page.

> If $k^2 = m + n$,
>
> $\sqrt m + \sqrt {2(k + \sqrt m)} = \sqrt {k + \sqrt n} + \sqrt {k + m - \sqrt n + 2\sqrt {m(k - \sqrt n)})}.$

For example,

$\sqrt 5 + \sqrt {2(11 + \sqrt 5)} = \sqrt {11 + \sqrt 116} + \sqrt {16 - \sqrt 116 + 2\sqrt {5(11 - \sqrt 116)})}.$

Do you know the short proof?

Comment: As it says, this  can be checked by squaring twice, while performing all simplifications, including substitution and observing a perfect square.

Comment: I have edited your expression - you might want to check what I have done

Comment: Try: to divide both sides by the one of the terms on the right or left and then multiply by its conjugate